# Can someone provide a working example using AccessibleChildren in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, children, accessible, iaccessible

I have been trying for months to work with the AccessibleChildren function in VB.Net, but I can't make it happen...

Can someone provide a working example of an application of AccessibleChildren that returns something meaningful?

Comment: Well, don't use it, it is only "easy" from C++ code.  Use System.Windows.Automation instead.  Google "system.windows.automation get children" for hits.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant!

To add some context: I am working on a VB.NET PowerPoint add-in and I need to get the text in a Ribbon combo-box. Is this possible?

I am reading up on System.Windows.Automation and trying to get the Ribbon children, but I don't know how to get started... 

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.peers.ribboncomboboxautomationpeer?view=net-5.0) looks like what I am looking for, but it only mentions C# and I can't get get any working example of System.Windows.Automation being used in VB.NET.

Can you help?